# Finding and counting a word mentioned inside a string (python 3)

Tags: python, string, iteration

I'm looking to find the number of times one string is mentioned inside another, counting it, and outputting the result. For instance, a program that finds how many times 'leg' appears in 'legaloglego'.

I tried to do it using a for loop that checks slices of the appropriate size (3 chars in this case) but get a Type error.

I appreciate your help.

This is the code I tried:

```
s = 'bobobslobbob'
i = 0
counter = -1
for i in s:
counter = counter + 1
    if s[i:i+2] == 'bob':
        i = i + 1    
print('Number of times bob occurs is:',counter)
```

Comment: So the expected output is `3` or `2`?

Comment: There are multiple problems with your code: 1) Your indentation is not correct 2) The counter should be incremented inside the `if` statement 3) You're incrementing `i` inside the loop, when you should be incrementing `counter` 4) `for i in s` iterates over the characters in `s`, not the indices. 5) You should be testing `s[i:i+3]` for a length 3 substring 6) Your counter should start at `0` (not `-1`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using `re.findall`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'bobobslobbob'
>>> 
>>> len(re.findall(r'(?=bob)', s))
3
```

Answer (score 0):

If not considering overlapping

```
s='bobobslobbob'
s.count('bob')
```